# Using an HTTP SMS API to send messages to mobiles

Tags: php, api

I've purchased access to an API for a SMS gateway so that I can send messages to mobile phones. They gave me a URL, a username and a password. I want to use this in my PHP program.

My SMS gateway provider gave me the following details:

> #### HTTP Api for single or multiple SMS
>
> ```
> http://yourURL/api/smsapi.aspx?username=yourUsername&password=yourPassword&to=9xxxxxxxxx,8xxxxxxxxx,7xxxxxxxxx&from=yourSenderId&message=Your message content.
> ```
>
> - username: Your login username.
> - password: Your login password.
> - to: Single mobile number or multiple mobile numbers separated by comma (Only 10 digits).
> - from: Approved sender id (Only 6 characters).
> - message: Your message content (Maximum 459 characters/3 messages).
>
>   - Note: Only 100 mobile numbers are allowed.

I tried many ways to use this, but I couldn't find a solution. How would I implement this in my PHP program?

Comment: If you purchased a gateway, you should contact the seller for support.  If you want anyone at SO to even take a look, you need to provide your code that is causing you problems, what you want to do, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: This seems quite unproffessional because you send the data unencrypted. A serious gateway offers HTTPS support.

Comment: no sir , i tried but they say , they provide only api not support programming??

Answer (score 1):

use CURL to call api.CURL is better way to call api.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://yourURL/api/smsapi.aspx?username=yourUsername&password=yourPassword&to=9xxxxxxxxx,8xxxxxxxxx,7xxxxxxxxx&from=yourSenderId&message=Your message content.';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: but how use curl in php ???

Comment: If I could downvote your comment, I would. The code provided here is php.